# install elasticsearch in openshift

Tags: elasticsearch, openshift

clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io is forbidden: 
User "" cannot create clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io at the cluster scope: no RBAC policy matched

I want to install elasticsearch6.7.0 in openshift online.
So, I downloaded the Elasticsearch image and set the variables.

However, the bootstrap.check failed and the Elasticsearch did not start.

So I want to set the vm.max_map_count = 262144 option.
[image: initContainers]
[image: containerLog]

However, I can not run the settings because of permissions.

Where do I set up these permissions?
or
Can I create an Elasticsearch image with the vm.max_map_count option?

Comment: To configure kernel parameter using `sysctl` dynamically, it's required root permission. For running pod as root, `anyuid` or `privileged` scc should grant to serviceaccount, but it can only cluser-admin role do. AFAIK, unfortunately OpenShift Online does not allow granting the cluster-admin role to regular user account. For more correct information, you had better to reach out the support desk. I hope it help you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a Elasticsearch image with your scc set as `restricted`, you will need to disable mmap. You can do this by specifying the environment variable `node.store.allow_mmap="false"` on your Elasticsearch pod(s).